# Unable to mock __subclasses__ in python

Tags: python, mocking

Why does the following code not work?

```
>>> from mock import *
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
...
>>> mock = create_autospec(A)
>>> mock.foo = Mock()                # this works
>>> mock.__bar__ = Mock()            # this works too
>>> mock.__subclasses__ = Mock()     # this fails
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute '__subclasses__'
```

I *think* I'm following the documentation on mocking magic methods here. The docs *do* remark that trying to mock a magic method which is not in the spec will not work. But why would `__subclasses__` *not* be in the spec of an autospecced new-style class?

Comment: I'm not sure that auto-speccing supports classes; `__subclasses__` is a method on `type` (the *metaclass* of `A`), and the resulting `mock` is itself not a type (you cannot use it to create instances). `isinstance(mock(), mock)` won't work either, for example.

Comment: The documentation states that you can mock magic methods, including ``__subclasses__``. So it is possible to create a mock that mimics a class, including ``__subclasses__``. Not using the above code, though.

Comment: But `__subclasses__` is not a magic method on `object`; it is a magic method on `type`, which is the type of `object` (`type(object)` gives `type`), which is where magic methods are always looked up. Think `object.__hash__` on instances; that's looked up on the class, and `type.__hash__` on classes; magic methods always have to bypass the instance.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there some magic going on? I thought that ``__subclasses__`` is only looked up on type because of the MRO. If you create a class that defines ``__subclasses__`` as a class or static method, that one is used instead. On a mock, created using ``create_autospec``, I can assign new mocks to new methods, including magic methods. I updated my question accordingly. But assigning to ``__subclasses__`` fails.

Comment: Sure, creating your own `__subclasses__` method on a class would shadow the one on `type` *when looking up the method directly*. Python never does that; when it needs to call a magic method it uses `type(obj).__magic_method__(obj, ...)`.

Comment: Ah, when it calls the magic methods *implicitly*. Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__subclasses__` is *not* part of the class spec. It is part of the *metatype* of the class (`type` here).

Python always [looks up special methods on the type](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup-for-new-style-classes), never directly. If and when Python needs to call `__subclasses__`, it'll not do so directly, it'll use `type(classobj).__subclasses__(classobj)` to look up the unbound method and pass in the first argument manually. As such, adding `__subclasses__` to the mock of a class is not going to be enough.

The same applies to special methods intended to operate on instances; `Mock` will happily take `__add__` or `__str__` along when using `create_autospec()`, and that works then for *instances* of the mocked class where Python will use `type(mockinstance).__str__(mockinstance)` to invoke the `__str__` method.

If your own code calls `classobj.__subclasses__()` directly, you'll need to pass in a class mock that *explicitly* sets that method; you can't expect it to be auto-specced here.

Mocks don't like you setting any *valid* magic method:

```
>>> m = create_autospec(A)
>>> m.__add__ = Mock()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock.py", line 767, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute '%s'" % name)
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute '__add__'
```

only non-default magic methods are allowed:

```
>>> m.__dummy__ = Mock()
>>> m.__dummy__
<Mock name='mock.__dummy__' id='4427608656'>
```

You can create a subclass of `A` adding in the `__subclass__` method to allow you to mock it:

```
>>> class AMockSpec(A):
...     def __subclasses__(self): pass
...
>>> m = create_autospec(AMockSpec)
>>> m.__subclasses__ = Mock()
>>> m.__subclasses__.return_value = ['SomeMockValue']
>>> m.__subclasses__()
['SomeMockValue']
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the link. My code does call ``__subclasses__()`` directly. I'm ok with explicitly setting that method in my mock. But when I have a mock returned from ``create_autospec()``, I can explicitly set various methods and attributes which were not part of the original class. However, it is not possible to set ``__subclasses__``, and I'm still not sure why.

Comment: @DavidFokkema: because you cannot set **any** magic method unless the original spec has one. The work-around is to create a spec subclass of the class.

Answer (score 0):

The following does work (`__subclasses__` is available on `__class__`):

```
>>> from mock import *
>>> class A(object):
...     pass
...
>>> m = create_autospec(A)
>>> m.__class__.__subclasses__()
[]
>>> class B(A): pass
...
>>> m.__class__.__subclasses__()
[<class '__main__.B'>]
>>> m.__class__.__subclasses__ = Mock()
>>> m.__class__.__subclasses__()
<Mock name='mock()' id='4372594896'>
```

Comment: This works because ``m`` is a mock of class ``A``. Thus, ``m.__class__`` points to ``A``. And ``m.__class__.__subclasses__`` are the subclasses of ``A``. You can mock that method, but that is not the same as ``m.__subclasses__``. Therefore, if I have code under test that uses ``__subclasses__`` to inspect all subclasses and act on them, the mock won't work.

Comment: So how will this help the OP or answer their question as to why `__subclasses__` isn't part of the mock *directly*? They still can't use the mock to test if their code is calling `mockedclass.__subclasses__`. `m.__class__` is not the mock anymore, that's just the original `A` class again.