# Python MagicMock how to mock __contains__ method

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, magicmock

I have defined the following class:

```
class Config:

     def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._entries = dict()
 
    @property
    def entries(self):
        return self._entries
    
    def __contains__(self, key: any) -> bool:

        """
        Returns True if specified key is in the existing config
        entries, else returns False.
        """

        return key in self.entries
```

I then have another class that is calling `Config.__contains__` through:

```
def some_function():
    config_obj = Config()
    if entry in config_obj:
        # Do something.
```

Now, I want to unit-test `some_function` and mock `Config.__contains__`. To do so, I have defined this test function:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def test_some_function()
    
    # given
    mocked_config_obj = Config()
    mocked_config_obj.__contains__ = MagicMock(return_value=True)
       
    # when
    some_function()

    # then
    mocked_config_obj.__contains__.assert_called_once() # Fails
```

Ideally, `if entry in config_obj` should call `mocked_config_obj.__contains__`, but it's not. What am I missing here?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268916/unable-to-mock-subclasses-in-python/30276073#30276073) answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

You're never actually mocking anything. You've created a `MagicMock` object and assigned it to a variable named `mocked_config_obj`, but you never patch the module containing `some_function` to use that mocked object.

Assuming that we have module `config.py` that implements the `Config` class:

```
class Config:

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._entries = dict()

    @property
    def entries(self):
        return self._entries

    def __contains__(self, key: any) -> bool:

        """
        Returns True if specified key is in the existing config
        entries, else returns False.
        """

        return key in self.entries
```

And module `some_module.py` that implements `SomeClass`, which uses `config.Config`:

```
from config import Config


class SomeClass:
    def some_function(self, entry):
        config_obj = Config()
        if entry in config_obj:
            print("doing something")
```

Then we could write a test like this:

```
from unittest import mock

import some_module

def test_some_function():
    with mock.patch('some_module.Config') as mock_config_obj:
        mock_config_obj.return_value.__contains__.return_value = True
        obj = some_module.SomeClass()
        obj.some_function("entry")

        mock_config_obj.return_value.__contains__.assert_called_with('entry')
```

That arranges for `config_obj = Config()` to receive a mock object, which we can then test for calls once `some_function` returns.